# Why are we not allowed to edit Job ads?

Tags: discussion, edits, stack-overflow-jobs

I will occasionally run into questions or answers in Stack Overflow where Java is written as if it was an [acronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym), all with uppercase letters. Obviously this is not the case, and I simply edit such content.

However, I find it quite funny where I see job ads looking for Senior, Superhuman, 10+ years experienced, *full stack* [JAVA Developers](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/171120/java-developer-pega-prpc-solution-architect-objectwise-consulting-group?med=clc).

This is not like typing Pytn instead of Python, which would obviously be an honest mistake, this I think resembles looking for someone with *Html* and *Css* experience together with *JAVA*. (Html and Css together with JAVA, if you know what I mean..)

So, would it be a good idea to be able to edit Job ads **only grammatically** so at least we do not spread the disease?

Comment: I personally don't want to work for a company who, in an attempt to get me to apply, don't even care enough to proofread their ads. Typos, grammatical mistakes and the like are red flags that this is a company I don't want to work for, so I say leave the mistakes in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it wouldn't be a good idea to allow editing of job ads.

The Q&A is about building a repository of high-quality questions and answers for future reference. It's about the content, not the person who posted it. So editing makes sense.

The job site is about employers looking for employees.

- **Any given ad is not intended to provide value to the internet as a whole.** It's about the specific needs of the company, not what would be useful to the internet as a whole.
- **Ads are inherently temporary.** There are Q&A posts that are about a decade old now, and they're still going strong. Ads tend to become obsolete after a few weeks. This is maybe less important than the other points, but it's not that beneficial to put effort into fixing something that'll stop being relevant in a month.
- **Ads are about the poster.** The exact wording and formatting of the content tells you a lot about the company (to be taken with a pinch of salt, but still), and that's useful information. I'd prefer to know what exactly a company wrote, including any mistakes that may have been made, instead of seeing the "ideal version" of an ad that's mostly been rewritten by someone who has absolutely nothing to do with the company.

If the company really cared about avoiding grammatical or spelling errors, they'd hire a proofreader, not expect some random volunteering stranger to fix that for them.

Answer (score 4):

It is my understanding that Jobs and Job descriptions are paid for advertisements by companies. They're not part of the usual Q/A, and I can't imagine staff or the companies paying for the listings would accept the possibility of community members editing them.

"only grammatically" is really hard to detect without manual review. And with manual review, you could just as well let the reviewer (staff advertising team or company contacts) do the editing themselves.

Comment: *I can't imagine staff or the companies paying for the listings would accept the possibility of community members editing them.* I can just imagine the level of yelling that would happen if someone edited a job's tags or changed the intent.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing the other responses here: since job listings are paid advertisements describing a specific opportunity at a specific company, community edits aren’t appropriate. It isn’t shared content, it’s a representation of a company’s brand & culture. We do provide advice to our customers on improving their listings, but ultimately it’s their content.

That said, there *are* ways we can work with the community on improving jobs. Several attributes (e.g. tags, role) are automatically inferred based on the job content and could likely benefit from additional input (e.g. user-suggested tags for better classification & discovery of jobs). Additionally, we’re currently looking into adding ways for users to provide feedback on job listings & application forms so that we can better identify high-quality listings.

We’re in early discovery for new features on this front and should have more to share in the coming months.