# Add possibility to leave feedback on a jobs advertisment

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, comments

### TL;DR

It would be nice to have the option to give feedback to a company that placed a job advertisement.

#### Background - long story

I stumbled upon a jobs add and found this passage

> Aufgrund des Teamworks innerhalb der Entwicklung und der
> Zusammenarbeit mit anderen Abteilung, findet Ihre Tätigkeit bei uns
> zwischen 8 Uhr vormittags und 20 Uhr am Abend statt.

This means loosely translated

```
Based on our teamwork with other departments your work 
will take place between 8:00 o'clock and 20:00 o'clock
```

I am not interested in the job but i would be willing to give feedback to tell them that this could be understood that the candidate has to expect that the company may insist that he works at these hours.

The *Company Benefits* list suggest that they have flexible work hours - but the last sentence might be understood that they do not have flexitime `Gleitzeit` where the employee decides - maybe within mandatory core working hours `Kernarbeitszeit`  - at which hours he wants to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a report feature on job listings that you can use to provide such feedback. Our support team reads all reports and will pass along the feedback to the company.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Overall I don't think adding this feature request would be worth the effort.

- Needing to give feedback on a job ad doesn't seem like it would be particularly common.
- Some users may try to use this feedback channel to try to circumvent the standard application process, which may just be a hassle for companies to deal with.
- Companies may not necessarily even want feedback on their job ads (this request is ultimately about them more than it is about the users giving feedback).

  Someone needs to be paid to look at all the feedback which, in most cases, probably doesn't really affect who applies. Also, spending that money on a proofreader would probably give a better cost/benefit ratio.

This also seems somewhat related to [Why are we not allowed to edit Job ads?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371265/why-are-we-not-allowed-to-edit-job-ads)

- Ads are inherently temporary. By the time they get to your feedback, they may already have received the bulk of their applications for that position, at which point editing it may not be that useful (although it may be useful if they repost or reuse the ad).
- The exact wording and formatting of the content (including any mistakes made) tells you a lot about the company (to be taken with a pinch of salt, but still).